# Stuck to append Images Using Azure Append blob in C#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

can I append Images byte... ? I tried that but not works.. its increase the size but not reflect images.. its always return first image that I append first.. So Please help how can I append images ? json/text files are working fine but I m stuck on append image..

So,Please Help how can i do that..

Here is my code

```
        CloudAppendBlob cloudAppendBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetAppendBlobReference(fileName);
        bool exist = await cloudAppendBlob.ExistsAsync();
        if(!exist)
        {
            await cloudAppendBlob.CreateOrReplaceAsync();
        }
        cloudAppendBlob.Properties.ContentType = fileType;
        stream.Position = 0;
        
        await cloudAppendBlob.AppendBlockAsync(stream);
```

Comment: Why are you using append blobs for this? It is completely a wrong use case for append blobs. You should be using block blobs for binary content.

Comment: @GauravMantri because in  my use-case, I want to create one API which will take parts of Images. and one by one these parts should be uploaded in azure. and it should create one image in azure. for that I using Append blob. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: Block blob is the way for this (and that's why it is named Block Blob). You would use [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) to add parts of the images and then stitch them together to get the image by using [`Put Block List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block-list).

Answer (score 0):

You can not append images with the same name. If you do that, it will replace the image file with the same name. If you upload another image then it would create a new image as per the uploaded one. Try the code below.

private CloudBlobContainer blobContainer;

```
    public AzureBlobHelper()
    {
      
        try
        {
            // Get azure table storage connection string.  

            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            blobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageContainer"));

            // Create the container and set the permission  
            if (blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
            {
                blobContainer.SetPermissions(
                    new BlobContainerPermissions
                    {
                        PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                    }
                );
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ExceptionObj)
        {
           // throw ExceptionObj;
        }
    }

    public string UploadFile(string FileName, string LocalPath, string AzureBlobPath, string ContentType = "")
    {
        string AbsoluteUri;

        try
        {
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob;
            // Create a block blob  
            blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(AzureBlobPath + FileName);
            // Set the object's content type  
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = ContentType;
            
            blockBlob.UploadFromFile(LocalPath);
            // get file uri  
            AbsoluteUri = blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }
        catch (Exception ExceptionObj)
        {
            throw ExceptionObj;
        }
        return AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

Comment: `You can not append images with the same name` - This is not correct. You can certainly append data to an existing append blob. However one should not be using append blob with binary content as it will corrupt the data. Block blobs should be used as you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Right. That's what we tried to explain as in the code. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried with your logic but it is overwriting with old image. so its not works for me. 
In my use-case, I want to create one API which will take parts of Images. and one by one these parts should be uploaded in azure. and it should create one image in azure.